# Googleドライブのフォルダ階層を記録したい

Tags: google-apps-script

Googleドライブのフォルダ階層を記録したいのですが、いい方法が思いつきません。
用途としては、共有フォルダ内のアイテムのIDを定期的に記録して、誤って移動してしまった際にGoogle Apps Scriptから復元するためです。その際、フォルダ階層を記録しておかないと、どのフォルダに復元するかがわからなくなりますので、フォルダ階層をスプレッドシートかどこかに保管しておきたいです。
どうすればよいでしょうか、教えてください。

追記
DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId).getFolders() / .getFiles() でイテレータを取得し、スプレッドシートへ書き込むことには成功しています。

Folder
└Folder
└Folder
　└Folder
　　└Folder
　└Folder
　　└Folder
　　└Folder

こんな感じのフォルダ階層を記録したいです。(この形でなくても、フォルダ階層の全体像がつかめ、ファイルやフォルダの復元時にどのフォルダに入っていたかがわかる形式ならば何でもいいです)

Answer (score 1):

DriveAppから getFolders(), getFiles() で1階層ずつファイルの情報を収集してスプレッドシート化するといいのではないでしょうか？

"Class DriveApp  |  Apps Script  |  Google Developers"
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app

ただ、ファイル数やフォルダ数が多いと情報取得の実行に時間が掛かりすぎて途中でエラーになるかもしれませんよ。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。階層ごとの取得には成功し、スプレッドシートに記録もできました。ただ、フォルダ階層の全体像を記録しておかないと、それぞれのフォルダをどのフォルダの中に作成すればいいのかが復元時にわからなくなってしまうのではないかと思います。この階層の全体を記録する方法はないでしょうか

Comment: 階層ごとの情報は取得できたんですよね？

いちいち階層をハンドリングするのは面倒なので、階層とファイルのIDをFull Path化して記録しておけば、ファイルのIDで検索するだけで復元先の階層がすぐに分かるのではないでしょうか。

それと Full Path化しておくとスプレッドシート上での並べ替えが簡単ですし、各階層にバラすのも簡単で加工しやすいですよ。